# HTML TABLES EXCEL PHP MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, export-to-excel

I am attempting to export mysql data into excel. I have tried the phpexcel class, and cannot use this on my host, as they do not have the zip function installed. I cannot export the data to csv, as the client 'wants to see purty colors...' so formatting is a must. So it looks like I am stuck building a table to pass to Excel. (unless anyone has any ideas on other classes!)

I am having an issue with the code, it exports just fine to excel and the formatting is correct for the first row. On all subsequent rows, all data is 'dumped' into one cell. 
Here is the code:

```
$table .= '<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"><tr>'; 
        $table .= '<td style="background-color:#000099;color:#FFFFFF;">Date</td>';
        $table .= '<td style="background-color:#000099;color:#FFFFFF;">Name</td>';
        $table .= '<td style="background-color:#000099;color:#FFFFFF;">Address</td>';
        $table .= '<td style="background-color:#000099;color:#FFFFFF;">City</td>';
        $table .= '</tr>';
        while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
        $table .= '<tr>';
        $table .= '<td style="background-color:#FFFCCC">'.$row['date'].'</td>';
        $table .= '<td style="background-color:#FFFCCC">'.$row['name'].'</td>';
        $table .= '<td style="background-color:#FFFCCC">'.$row['address'].'</td>';
        $table .= '<td style="background-color:#FFFCCC">'.$row['city'].'</td>';
        $table .= '</tr>';
        $table .= '</table>';
        }
header("Pragma: public");
header("Expires: 0");
header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0"); 
header("Content-Type: application/force-download");
header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
header("Content-Type: application/download");;
header("Content-Disposition: attachment;filename=Itinerary-$today.xls "); 
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary ");
echo $table;
```

Appreciate any thoughts anyone can share on this subject!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try moving this line:

```
$table .= '</table>';
```

to outside the loop.

The last few lines of the loop should looke like:

```
    $table .= '</tr>';
}
$table .= '</table>';
```

You opened a table *before* the loop, you should close the table *after* the loop.

Comment: DOH! Palm slap to my forehead! Many Thanks!

Comment: @matt colley: The technical term for that is "face-palm" ;)

Answer (score 0):

Export it with CSV and then import it on your localhost, now re-export it and have pretty export functions working. Maybe you need to install a LAMP stack on your PC, handy to have anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You're closing the table in the wrong place.

It should be outside of the `while`.